# Error message: Object of abstract class type "X" is not allowed: Pure virtual "Y" has no overrider

Tags: c++

Enemy.h

```
class Enemy
{
    int hp;
public:
    Enemy(int);
    void setHP(int);
    int getHP();
    virtual int attack() = 0;
};
```

Enemy.cpp

```
Enemy::Enemy(int playerXP)
{
    if (playerXP == 0) {
        hp = rand() % 5 + 1;
    }
    else if (playerXP > 0) {
        hp = rand() % (playerXP * 5) + 1;
    }
}

void Enemy::setHP(int currentHP)
{
    hp = currentHP;
}

int Enemy::getHP()
{
    return hp;
}
```

Reaper.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Enemy.h"

class Reaper : public Enemy
{
public:
    Reaper(int playerXP) : Enemy(playerXP)
    {   
    }

    int attack(int, int);
};
```

Reaper.cpp

```
int Reaper::attack(int pa, int php)
{
    int eatk = 0;
    if (pa == 0) {
        eatk = php * .5;
    }
    else {
        eatk = rand() % php * .25;
    }
    return eatk;
}
```

Error:

> Object of abstract class type "Reaper" is not allowed: 
>   Pure virtual function "Enemy:attack" has no overrider.

My question is.. Why am I getting this error?  I'm trying to understand why I am getting this, and also any possible answers to solve it.

Comment: If you want a function to override another you can use the `override` keyword to ensure that it is in fact overriding. The compiler will provide better error messages and some IDEs will show the potential compilation error as you're typing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Reaper` is abstract because it is not **overriding** the abstract `Enemy::attack()` method, it is **overloading** it instead.  As such, you cannot create any object instances of `Reaper` directly.

When a derived class wants to *override* a virtual method of a base class, the derived method MUST have the same signature as the base method it is overriding.  That means it has the same return type (or at least a compatible [covariant return type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type)), calling convention, parameter list, and constness.

`Reaper::attack()` has a different parameter list than `Enemy::attack()`.  That is why `Reaper::attack()` is an *overload* instead of an *override*.

In C++11 and later, you can (and should) mark `Reaper::attack()` with the new [`override` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override), eg:

```
class Reaper : public Enemy
{
public:
    ...    
    int attack(int, int) override;
};
```

That way, the compiler will take extra steps to verify whether a compatible base method actually exists, and if none is found then it will issue more meaningful error messages.  For example, [this live demo](https://ideone.com/ajT81O) produces these errors when using `override` as shown above:

```
prog.cpp:41:9: error: ‘int Reaper::attack(int, int)’ marked ‘override’, but does not override
     int attack(int, int) override;
         ^~~~~~
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:57:9: error: cannot declare variable ‘r’ to be of abstract type ‘Reaper’
  Reaper r(0);
         ^
prog.cpp:34:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Reaper’:
 class Reaper : public Enemy
       ^~~~~~
prog.cpp:11:17: note:   virtual int Enemy::attack()
     virtual int attack() = 0;
                 ^~~~~~
```

Comment: How would i go about doing an override to attack() function?

Comment: @BrandonTorrens You have to remove the extra `int` parameters from `Reaper::attack()` so it matches `Enemy::attack()` exactly. That means you will have to find another way to pass your desired `pa` and `php` values to a `Reaper` object.

Comment: Good sir, thank you for your assistance, it worked, and i was able to improve the logic as well thanks to you, much appreciated.@RemyLebeau

Answer (score 4):

The compiler doesn't realize that you want to override the attack function in the base class. It sees `int attack()` and `int attack(int, int)` as two different functions because they have different type signatures. The result is that your `Reaper` class has two functions, one of which is a pure virtual function. Using the `override` keyword can help to avoid these errors, although it is only available in C++11 and newer.