# pure virtual function has no overrider

Tags: c++, virtual

Can anyone help me please?

I have this problem now, and cannot solve this.

> object of abstract class type is not allowed: pure virtual function has no overrider'

I highlighted below:

```
class State 
{ 
public:
    virtual void Update() = 0;
    virtual void Render();
    virtual void Enter() = 0;
    virtual void Exit() = 0;
    virtual void Resume() = 0;
protected:
    State() {} 
};

class GameState : public State
{
private:
    Level level;
    Level levels[5] = { Level(3), Level(1), Level(1), Level(2), Level(1) };
    const char* levelNames[5] = { "Level1.txt", "Level2.txt", "Level3.txt", "Level4.txt", "Level5.txt" };
    SDL_Texture* tileText;
    SDL_Texture* playerText;
    Player player;
    SDL_Surface* tileSurf;
    SDL_Surface* playerSurf;

    int m_iTickCtr = 0;
    int m_iTickMax = 1; // for animation

public:
    GameState() {}
    void Update(Level& l, Player& p, int& c) ; // Level& level, Player& player, int& c
    void Render(Level& l, Player& p);
    void Enter();
    void Exit();
    void Resume() { cout << "Resuming Game..." << endl; }
    enum sfx { jump, boom, laser };
};

class TitleState : public State
{
public:
    TitleState() {}
    virtual void Update();
    void Render();
    void Enter(); 
    void Exit();
    void Resume() {}
    enum btn { play, exit };
private: 
    vector<Button*> m_vButtons;
};

void TitleState::Update()
{
    /*
    if (Game::Instance()->KeyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_B) == 1)
        Game::Instance()->GetAM()->PlaySound(sfx::boop);
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)m_vButtons.size(); i++)
        m_vButtons[i]->Update();
    // Parse buttons.
    if (m_vButtons[btn::play]->Clicked())
        Game::Instance()->GetFSM()->ChangeState(new GameState()); // here 'GameState' has problems.
    else if (m_vButtons[btn::exit]->Clicked())
        Game::Instance()->DoQuit();
}
```

Comment: Yes, because `GameState` does not implement  several abstract functions you cannot construct a new instance of a `GameState` object, using `new`, or in any other way; so what exactly about this basic property of abstract, a.k.a. pure virtual, methods, you are asking about? Just by eyeballing the shown code, `GameState` fails to implement `Update()`, and `Render()`, so either implement them, or create some other object that implements them. That's it.

Comment: You should annotate all your overriders with  `override`, then you will very quickly spot the problem.

Comment: Don't forget about good ol' function overloading in C++: `void Update()` and `void Update(Level&, Player&, int&)` are **different functions**. You would benefit from adding the [`override`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198314/what-is-the-override-keyword-in-c-used-for) specifier to your functions in `GameState`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message: Object of abstract class type "X" is not allowed: Pure virtual "Y" has no overrider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50053589/error-message-object-of-abstract-class-type-x-is-not-allowed-pure-virtual-y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your subclass, `GameState`, you must create an override function for `void Update()`, which is defined as pure virtual in the abstract class, `State`.

Maybe you think you did so, because you created `void Update(Level& l, Player& p, int& c)`, but since this function has a different signature than `void Update()`, it does not override it.